# How to prevent come code deletion in DbContext while updating model in database first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have a database-first `DbContext` and I added some audit related code in the `DbContext` class, but when I update the model, it deleted my written code in `DbContext` class. Please tell me how to retain this code even after model update.

Here is my code and I added comments which code is deleting after model update:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=ODbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNotification> AspNotifications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ASPAudit> ASPAudit { get; set; }

    // this code is removed whenever I update model
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
         var addedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
         
        int changes = base.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var entry in addedEntries)
        {
           ...some code
        }

        base.SaveChanges();

        return changes;
    }
}
```

It would be great if anyone guide me

Comment: It's a partial class, you can add to the definition in another source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at top of that generated class, you'll see:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That means this class will be auto-generated on every update.

EF generated classes are [`partial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods), you can create and add your extensions/changes to other half of [`partial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) class (for example `MyDbContextPartial.cs`).

```
// file MyDbContextPartial.cs
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
         var addedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
         
        int changes = base.SaveChanges();
        foreach (var entry in addedEntries)
        {
           ...some code
        }

        base.SaveChanges();
        return changes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I created it with the same class name as 'MyDbContext' ?

Comment: How to access DbSet<Entity> in partial class.

Comment: @DeveloperDJ you can read about [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods), they are basically one class splitted in half (or many classes).